# Embedded code in repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am using a databound repeater component with some click-sensitive panel inside.

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelContent" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelMenuTitle" runat="server" 
                ondblclick="EditMenu(<%# Eval("ID") %>)">
```

As you can see I want to pass the ID of the current data item to a javascript function called EditMenu().

However, this code breaks due to "The server tag is not well formed.". I also tried everything I can think of: Using `<%=` instead of `<%#`, `Bind()` instead of `Eval()`, ' instead of " without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes around the ondblclick function. That should fix it. See below.

```
ondblclick='EditMenu(<%# Eval("ID") %>)'
```

My second suggestion would be to use another control, like a ListView or a DataList, so that you can assign data keys to hold the ID. Then you can assign the ondblclick event in the ItemDataBound event like this.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Panel pnlCtrl = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("Panel1");
        if (pnlCtrl != null)
        {
            pnlCtrl.Attributes["ondblclick"] = String.Format("EditMenu({0})", ListView1.DataKeys[((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DisplayIndex]["ID"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. Tried this before. The rendered markup looks like this: ... onclick="EditMenu(&lt;%# Eval(&quot;ID&quot;) %>)"> ...

Comment: This comment you just posted wraps the JavaScript function in double-quotes. Are you sure you tried with single quotes around the JavaScript function?

Comment: Yeah, I am very sure since I used copy&paste in order to copy your suggestion right in my code.

Comment: Yes, thank you James. That is working just fine. I adapted your code to my needs (with repeater instead of ListView) and now it works like a charm. Thanks so much again for your help!

Comment: Good stuff. Glad you got it working. How did you get around the data keys with the repeater? The repeater doesn's support data keys, does it??

Comment: I'm not sure, James. I never worked with data keys (don't even know what they are ;-)). As you can see, all I'm doing was referencing the DataItem (and it's ID property).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got it working. Not the original approach, but in the end it's what I wanted:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Panel pnlCtrl = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("PanelMenuTitle");
            if (pnlCtrl != null)
            {
                myMenu menu = (e.Item.DataItem as myMenu);
                pnlCtrl.Attributes["ondblclick"] = String.Format("EditMenu('{0}')", menu.ID);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Answer by OP moved from question.